# Complex array in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android

I have a list of the countries stored into XML, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="nation_array">
    <item>Afghanistan</item>
    <item>Albania</item>
    <item>Algeria</item>
    <item>American Samoa</item>
    <item>Andorra</item>
    <item>Angola</item>
    <item>Anguilla</item>
    <item>Antarctica</item>
    ................
</string-array>
</resources>
```

**Adapter:**

```
String[] countries = groupContent.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nation_array);
ArrayAdapter<String> nationAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mContext, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries);

autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(nationAdapter);
```

And everything works fine. But now it turned out that need to drop-down list to show the name of the country, but when sending a double-digit use the abbreviations of countries, such as United States - US.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<country-list>
<country>
    <name>Абхазия</name>
    <english>Abkhazia</english>
    <code>AB</code>
</country>
<country>
    <name>Австралия</name>
    <english>Australia</english>
    <code>AU</code>
</country>
<country>
    <name>Австрия</name>
    <english>Austria</english>
    <code>AT</code>
</country>
<country>
    <name>Азербайджан</name>
    <english>Azerbaijan</english>
    <code>AZ</code>
</country>
.............
</country-list>
```

**Q: How does it realize, tell me? Nowhere are such examples found**

Comment: instead of `ArrayAdapter<String>` use `ArrayAdapter<YourPOJO>` where `YourPOJO` holds both  country name and country code

Comment: Do not quite understand. Can be more...

Comment: see https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter